# How to earn epic points when no epic project is available?

Tags: simcity-buildit

I'd like to complete a task collecting 40 epic points. However, there's no epic project in my city at the moment. How can I collect epic points for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earning epic points when an epic project is not available is not possible. To do the Contest of Mayor’s assignment to collect 40 epic points, you need to start an epic project.